# C# Hashcode Return value

Tags: c#, hashcode

For a given string "5", if I use the built in GetHashCode() function what is the value that is returned? Am I confused in that it returns the integer value of 5?

Comment: It does not really matter - why do you want to know (it is a implementation detail)

Comment: the return value is -842352757
[check this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425142/what-is-hashcode-use-for-is-it-unique

Comment: [ideone](http://ideone.com/2XfZ68) gives 53.

Answer (score 5):

It's implementation specific, and you should not rely on anything you happen to observe in one particular implementation. Only rely on what is [*guaranteed*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx): two equal strings will return the same value, in the same process. The same string value *can* return a different hash next time you run your program, or on a different machine. This means you should never persist the result of `GetHashCode` - it's not useful for future comparisons.

If two strings return the same hash code they *may* be equal - but they may not be.

Comment: did't got your last line..please can you explain more?

Comment: there can be situations where two different strings produce the same hashcode (indeed there always will be)

Comment: Basically, hash codes can collide. If x.GetHashCode() is not equal to y.GetHashCode, then x and y are definitely not equal. If the two hashes are the same, they still *might* be unequal.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle  :D ... there are more strings than there are possible hash-values ;)

Comment: @Justcode ??? - what do you mean by: *gurantee* and **perfect** output? (What do you consider as perfect?) - What should the 2 fields be in the case of a string?

Comment: what tweaks(?) - the collisions? This is a unavoidable *problem* when you use hashes

Comment: @CarstenKönig I think I got it on *msdn* thanks for your response though

Answer (score 1):

For `string.GetHash()` [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) writes:

> If two string objects are equal, the GetHashCode method returns identical values. However, there is not a unique hash code value for each unique string value. Different strings can return the same hash code.
>
> The hash code itself is not guaranteed to be stable. Hash codes for identical strings can differ across versions of the .NET Framework and across platforms (such as 32-bit and 64-bit) for a single version of the .NET Framework. In some cases, they can even differ by application domain.
>
> As a result, hash codes should never be used outside of the application domain in which they were created, they should never be used as key fields in a collection, and they should never be persisted.
>
> Finally, do not use the hash code instead of a value returned by a cryptographic hashing function if you need a cryptographically strong hash. For cryptographic hashes, use a class derived from the System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm or System.Security.Cryptography.KeyedHashAlgorithm class.

So its kind of "quick-compare-check" feature regarding strings. But you should not relay on the hash-only. Its important to know that these hash-codes are not stable, meaning you must never store them in files, databases etc. - don't persist them.

In general `GetHash()` is specific to the class implementation as Jon wrote. If we look at the MSDN Docs for [`object.GetHash()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) we see that they serve as a index for hash-based collection so the collections index-tree is balanced. See this article for more information on [hasing-algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

So if you query one and the same object using `GetHash()` it should return the same hash-code. That code may be different if your application runs the next time.