# Mono equivalent of ClientConnectionId

Tags: c#, sql-server, mono, sqlclient

I would like to run this function under mono ( my current version is 4.0.2)

```
 public Object GetConnectionProperty(SqlConnection _conn, string prop)
    {
        if (_conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed &
            prop == "ServerVersion")
            return string.Empty;

        if (prop == "ClientConnectionId")
        {
            Guid guid = _conn.ClientConnectionId;
            return guid.ToString();
        }
        return _conn.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(_conn);
    }
```

But it fails with the error :

```
error CS1061: Type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' does not contain a 
definition for `ClientConnectionId' and no extension method 
`ClientConnectionId' of type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' could be 
found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

What is the Mono equivalent of `ClientConnectionId`? Or how can I fix it?

Comment: From the [source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs), `ClientConnectionId` is not implemented. Why do you need it? (to see if there is a workaround)

Comment: @manji good to know. I want to know if there is a workaround ffor exampel chech for the OS system or check for the compiler..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ClientConnectionId` is not implemented in mono [SqlConnection](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs) class. If you really want to have some unique identifier for each instance, you can do it yourself as having an id constructed from the hashcode for example:

```
public static class SqlClientExtensions {
#if __MonoCS__
    private static Dictionary<int, string> _connIds = new Dictionary<int, string>();
#endif

    public static string GetClientConnectionId(this SqlConnection conn) {
        if(conn == null) {
            return Guid.Empty.ToString();
        }

#if __MonoCS__
        if(!connIds.ContainsKey(conn.GetHashCode())) {
            connIds.Add(conn.GetHashCode(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }

        return connIds[conn.GetHashCode()];
#else
        return conn.ClientConnectionId.ToString();
#endif
    }
}
```

then you can use it in your method:

```
if (prop == "ClientConnectionId")
{
    return _conn.GetClientConnectionId();
}
```

#### *P.S.:*

The hash code may be repeated for 2 different instances at different points in time.

#### *P.S.(2):*

`__MonoCS__` is defined only by the mono compiler. The portion calling the `ClientConnectionId` property wil not be seen by mono compiler and vice versa for the other portion and .net compiler.

#### *P.S.(3):*

Another solution would be to subclass `SqlConnection` and implement `ClientConnectionId` but it's sealed... And also that would require subclassing some other classes that instantiate the `SqlConnection` class internally.

Comment: Excellent answer ! this will be part of [rsqlserver](https://github.com/agstudy/rsqlserver/commit/408ff64d4d46c693a34f34fdc181295c29badc0e) R package to connect from R to MS SQL Server.

Comment: Hash codes, by definition, are not guaranteed to be unique. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425142/what-is-hashcode-used-for-is-it-unique