# Group a 2d array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a 2d array of strings:

```
string[,] arr = new string[3,3]{
  { "a", "b", "c" }, 
  { "a", "b", "c" }, 
  { "d", "e", "f" }, 
}
```

The result I would like to get is:

`a,b,c` = 2

`d,e,f` = 1

I tried:

```
List<List<string>> lLString = new List<List<string>>();
string[,] stringArray2D = new string[3, 3] {
    { "a", "b", "c" }, 
    { "a", "b", "c" }, 
    { "d", "e", "f" }, 
};
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray2D.GetLength(0); i++) {
    List<string> temp = new List<string>();
    for (int j = 0; j < stringArray2D.GetLength(1); j++) { 
        temp.Add(stringArray2D[i,j]);
    }
    lLString.Add(temp);
}
```

trying to get it out by doing this :

`lLString.GroupBy (ls => ls);`

but doesn't seem right

Comment: So... what have you tried so far? And where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @bassfader - updated

Comment: Linq isn't compatible with multidimensional arrays. You chose the wrong instrument (multidimensional arrays) for your work. Not that with jagged arrays it would be easy (you would need an ArrayComparer)

Comment: @xaisoft: You say "I tried", but the posted code does not  show an attempt at grouping. You converted the multidimensional array to a jagged array (jagged _list_, I guess...), but you haven't actually tried to group them.

Comment: @Flater - I thought by converting it to a list first, I could call the groupby on it.

Comment: I think you would need to crate a class to hold the list that implement iequatable

Comment: No IDE but with a fucntion like this `IEnumerable<T> SelectRow<T>(this T[,] inputArray, int index){
 for(int i = inputArray.GetLowerBound(1); i <= inputArray.GetUpperBound(1); ++i)
  yield return inputArray[index, i];
}`, you select each row and group them. A lazy trick would be to concatenate by chunk that have the size of a row. 1 row into a big string

Answer (score 2):

You could have used directly a jagged array, like:

```
string[][] arrayJagged = new[]
{
    new[] { "a", "b", "c" },
    new[] { "a", "b", "c" },
    new[] { "d", "e", "f" },
    new[] { "g", "h", "i" },
};
```

but you want to dig in the ruins of the past and use multidimensional array, just to make everything more complex.

```
string[,] stringArray2D = new string[,] 
{
    { "a", "b", "c" },
    { "a", "b", "c" },
    { "d", "e", "f" },
    { "g", "h", "i" },
};
```

Then we will have to convert the multidimensional array to a jagged array:

```
string[][] arrayJagged = new string[stringArray2D.GetLength(0)][];

int length2 = stringArray2D.GetLength(1);

for (int i = 0; i < arrayJagged.Length; i++)
{
    arrayJagged[i] = new string[length2];

    for (int j = 0; j < length2; j++)
    {
        arrayJagged[i][j] = stringArray2D[i, j];
    }
}
```

Note that you don't really need a `List<List<string>>` because in the end the dimensions of the jagged array are predetermined.

Then you can `.GroupBy()` the jagged array, and do a `.Count()` on each group:

```
var grouped = arrayJagged.GroupBy(x => x, ArrayEqualityComparer<string>.Default)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.Key,
        Count = x.Count()
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Note that .NET doesn't have a default equality comparer for arrays, so you'll need to define one, to show the `.GroupBy()` how to check for equality of elements:

```
// Simple T[] IEqualityComparer<>
public sealed class ArrayEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T[]>, IEqualityComparer
{
    // One instance is more than enough
    public static readonly ArrayEqualityComparer<T> Default = new ArrayEqualityComparer<T>();

    // We lazily define it if necessary
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer;

    public ArrayEqualityComparer()
    {
        equalityComparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public ArrayEqualityComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer)
    {
        this.equalityComparer = equalityComparer;
    }

    /* IEqualityComparer<T[]> */

    public bool Equals(T[] x, T[] y)
    {
        if (x == null)
        {
            if (y == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        if (y == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return EqualsNotNull(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T[] obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;

            if (obj != null)
            {
                // This one will help distinguish between null and empty:
                // hash(null) == 17, hash(empty) == 17 * 23
                hash = (hash * 23) + obj.Length;

                for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length; i++)
                {
                    hash = (hash * 23) + obj[i].GetHashCode();
                }
            }

            return hash;
        }
    }

    /* IEqualityComparer */

    bool IEqualityComparer.Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        if (x == y)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (x == null || y == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var x2 = x as T[];

        if (x2 == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("x");
        }

        var y2 = y as T[];

        if (y2 == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("y");
        }

        return EqualsNotNull(x2, y2);
    }

    int IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        T[] obj2;

        if (obj != null)
        {
            obj2 = obj as T[];

            if (obj2 == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("obj");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            obj2 = null;
        }

        return GetHashCode(obj2);
    }

    /* Implementation */

    private bool EqualsNotNull(T[] x, T[] y)
    {
        if (x.Length != y.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (x.Length != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!equalityComparer.Equals(x[i], y[i]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't use a jagged array because I read an excel sheet into a 2d array and it is read as [,]

Comment: What is GetHashCode for?

Comment: @xaisoft Because `GroupBy` uses it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425142/what-is-hashcode-used-for-is-it-unique

Comment: Everything looks great.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a class the overrides equals

```
public static void GroupList()
{
    List<ListComp> lLString = new List<ListComp>();
    string[,] stringArray2D = new string[3, 3] { { "a", "b", "c" },
                                                 { "a", "b", "c" },
                                                 { "d", "e", "f" },
                                                };
    for (int i = 0; i<stringArray2D.GetLength(0); i++) {
        ListComp temp = new ListComp();
        for (int j = 0; j<stringArray2D.GetLength(1); j++) { 
            temp.Add(stringArray2D[i, j]);
        }
        lLString.Add(temp);
    }
    var gr = lLString.GroupBy(i => i);

    foreach (var g in gr)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{g.Key} = {g.Count()}");
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("");
}
public class ListComp : List<string>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(",", this);
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        ListComp listComp = obj as ListComp;
        if (listComp == null)
            return false;
        else
            return Equals(listComp);
    }
    public bool Equals(ListComp listComp)
    {
        if (listComp == null)
            return false;

        return this.SequenceEqual(listComp);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 1;
        foreach(string s in this)
        {
            hash *= s.GetHashCode();
        }
        return hash;
    }
    public ListComp (List<string> listComp)
    {
        this.AddRange(listComp);
    }
    public ListComp()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a basic for loops similar to the one you used create a list of strings. Then use the `GroupBy`.

```
string[,] arr = new string[3, 3]
{
        { "a", "b", "c" },
        { "a", "b", "c" },
        { "d", "e", "f" },
};

int dim1 = arr.GetLength(0);
int dim2 = arr.GetLength(1);

List<string> temp = new List<string>();
string st;
for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++)
{
    st = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++)
        st += arr[i, j] + ",";
    temp.Add(st);
}

var gr = temp.GroupBy(i => i);

foreach (var g in gr)
    Console.WriteLine($"{g.Key} = {g.Count()}");
```

**Output:**

`a,b,c, = 2
d,e,f, = 1`

Comment: is there a way to do this without concatenating the strings?